# Using javascript variable on html <a>

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I have this javascript code:

```
<script ="text/javascript">
    var newUrl=window.location.href;
    var pathArray="";
    pathArray=newUrl.substr(newUrl.lastIndexOf("?")+1);
</script>
```

I want to use the pathArray variable as a part of my href on the  tag

This is my html code

```
<a href="game.html?"+pathArray>
  <img src="img/RestartButton.png" style="position:absolute;
  left:80px; top:220px">
</a>
```

but it seems like it doesn't read the value if the variable, but the name of it instead.

Comment: Sorry, but you can't just dump the name of a Javascript variable anywhere in your HTML markup and expect it to work.

Comment: Wouldn't the pathArray variable will be a global variable, because it's on the HTML file?

Comment: HTML and Javascript are two different things... HTML doesn't _have_ variables. It certainly doesn't have Javascript's. HTML also doesn't have an `+` operator for arguments. It's a markup language, not a programming language.

Answer (score 9):

You're mixing your javascript into your HTML.

I believe your pathArray variable will also not contain what you are expecting.

Try this in your script tag:

```
var gamePath = "game.html?" + window.location.search.replace( "?", "" );
document.getElementById("gameAnchor").setAttribute("href", gamePath);
```

And add an id to your anchor:

```
<a href="#" id='gameAnchor'>
```

The javascript will get all `GET` parameters from the current url and then replace the `href` attribute in the element with an id of `gameAnchor` with your game.html concatenated with the `GET` parameters in the url.

Answer (score 1):

You can't place a javascript variable anywhere in html.
Instead you need to get the dom element through script and append the href attribute.
give your anchor an id or classname and try this as an example.

```
<a id="myLink" href="game.html">
    <img src="img/RestartButton.png" style="position:absolute;left:80px; top:220px">
</a>

<script type="text/javascript">;
    document.getElementById('myLink').href += window.location.search
</script>
```

Comment: Instead of dumping code on the OP, why not _explain_ the solution?

Comment: I've tried that, but it keeps giving me this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'href' of null at file:///android_asset/www/lose.html?level1:8

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use JavaScript for this as well. First give your anchor an ID:

`<a id="myLink" href="game.html?"><img src="img/RestartButton.png" style="position:absolute;    left:80px; top:220px"></a>`

And then add following to your JavaScript code:

`document.getElementById('myLink').href += pathArray;`

The code will add the content of your string variable to href property of anchor element.

Answer (score 1):

First, make the anchor easier to select by giving it an identifier.

`<a href="#" id="pathLink"></a>` (This is assuming there is more than one anchor on your page)

Then, in your script above include:

```
var anchor = document.getElementById("pathLink");
```

The anchor tag has a native href property, so assigning the new one is as easy as this:

Rewrite:

```
var anchor = document.getElementById("pathLink").href += pathArray;
```

Answer (score 1):

It won't work like that. You will have to loop through the anchors your need using JavaScript.

This hasn't been tested. I'm assuming you want this to happen to more than one anchor link.

HTML:

```
<a class="updatethis" href="game.html">...</a>
<a href="not-game.html">...</a>
<a class="udpatethis" href="game.html">...</a>
```

JavaScript:
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

```
for (var i = 0, a; a = anchors[i++]; ) {
    if (a.className === 'updatethis') {
        a.href += window.location.search;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access an attribute of an element in HTML. Although it's not really an HTML variable, it's roughly close to it. As you expect from a variable, you can `get`, `set` and `remove` it.

**Element.getAttribute()** :

> getAttribute() returns the value of a specified attribute on the element. If the given attribute does not exist, the value returned will either be null or "" (the empty string); see Notes for details : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

Example :

```js
let myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
console.log(myDiv.getAttribute("variable"))
```

```html
 <div class="div" id="myDiv" variable='test'</div>
```

Of course, you can set, or remove an attribute too :

**Element.setAttribute()**

> Sets the value of an attribute on the specified element. If the
>   attribute already exists, the value is updated; otherwise a new
>   attribute is added with the specified name and value.

**Element.removeAttribute()**

> Blockquote

removeAttribute removes an attribute from the specified element.

*Note*:
This being said, you will need javascript to interact with attributes. And that explains partially why it's not a "proper variable".

Answer (score -1):

Think of using some template engine as undescore, moustache or doT.js. you can easily substitute html identifier or part of with template's data variables.