# Update most recent file (href URL) across multiple html files

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a link that exists on multiple different html files, and I want to be able to update some kind of `mostRecentURL` var/object/class/id/attribute somewhere in a (.js or .css?) file instead of having to change the link in every file individually.

Researching this I found this question: [Using javascript variable on html <a>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894638/using-javascript-variable-on-html-a)

But I'm confused by the different methods. The second answer seemed to be multiple peoples answers, though the first answer had the highest score.

Are these good ways of trying to do what I'm trying to do? What's the difference between those strategies? Are there advantages/disadvantages to using one over the other?

Thanks!

EDIT: The goal is to have a link that is on /index.html, /other.html, and /something.html. The link is to the most recent article (/article3.html). Every time there is a new article I would like to be able to change something in one place so that everywhere the link is, it now links to /article4.html.

EDIT (again): Would it be possible to simply use CSS like...

```
a {
     href: "URL";
}
```

If not, why not?

Comment: if that is all you're trying to do -   good ol' CTRL + F  and find all instances of your search and change them out

Comment: That would work, but I'm trying to have an efficient way of maintaining the website, on top of it just being a learning experience.

Comment: The efficient way would be using database. Change once in database and check from other pages 'which is the most recent url'

Comment: You could also look at using some sort of flatfile CMS like Jekyll for this. It's a script you run locally that builds your site (including relative links) based on files in certain folders. It could very easily point a link at whatever the newest post is.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, could you post some example of what you're trying to do?

If you're just changing things once, I'd suggest a good ol' fashioned find-and-replace.

If it's changing dynamically, and if all these links have a class or something that identifies them, you could do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var mostRecentURL = "http://foo.bar/foobar";
    $('.dynamicURL').attr('href', mostRecentURL);
});
```

where all the elements with the class 'dynamicUrl' get their `href` attributes changed to whatever your new URL is when the page loads (or whenever else you want).

Comment: I added an edit that will hopefully clear things up. Is the above in... javascript? (sorry i'm pretty new to webdev)

Comment: ha - I didn't even read your answer  we suggested the same thing ,  all the way down to saying " good ol' " find and replace

Comment: Charles — That's some javascript leveraging the jQuery library. You could write it in pure javascript too, but this is a little easier. This would have to be in an external javascript file that's linked to in every file you want the URL to be replaced in.

Scott — Great minds and all!

Answer (score 0):

In your links call a js function. Create a global variable and use it to return URI.

The mostRecentURL can be updated by invoking javascript to change the global variable.

```
var mostRecentURL = "www.google.com";

function mostRecentURL() {
    return mostRecentURL; 
}
```

Comment: Trying this.. will let you know how it goes.

Comment: How would I go about calling the function in the link? Not `href=function()` im realizing...

Comment: That's exactly what I did, though instead of linking to the proper link, it goes to domain.com/mostRecentURL. I couldn't say why it wasn't working.

Comment: are you missing the brackets? Can you post your code?