# How to get the link name when clicked?

Tags: javascript

```
window.onclick = function(e) { var url = e.target;
alert(url);
e.preventDefault();
};
```

// I am getting the link but I need the link name to be alerted.

Comment: What do you mean by the link "name"?  Are you referring to the anchor tag's `name` attribute?  Also, that isn't how you call `addEventListener`.

Comment: This code doesn't run.  Edit your question with code that can be  run, preferably with a runnable snippet.

Comment: I get *Uncaught ReferenceError: target is not defined*. Provide a real [mcve]

Comment: look for target.attr

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894638/using-javascript-variable-on-html-a

Comment: Have you looked at the actual API for [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)?  It's a member of `HTMLElement`.

Comment: <a href="https://www.example.com">Visit example.com!</a>

I want "Visit example.com!" to be alerted

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns an array like object, your code is binding an event to the window object.  Further, `target` is not defined.  Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @zero298 — You should read that documentation again. It is a member of all EventTargets, including `window`. Binding it there is a standard technique for dealing with event delegation.

Comment: @Quentin and HTMLElement implements EventTarget so it has `addEventListener` as a member.  I'm trying to hint to the OP that they need to actually call the function on the element, not just call it bare.

Comment: @zero298 — So does `window` which is what they are (implicitly) calling it on.

Answer (score -2):

AS you are working on Javascript, use `this.getAttribute('href')`.

Now you can alert this or use this in some variable :)

Comment: You don't need jQuery for this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @zero298